# Intellij 12.1.6 (Community), Creating Grails project, Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: grails for class: BuildConfig

Tags: grails, groovy, intellij-idea

I was following [this](http://keaplogik.blogspot.in/p/developing-grails-web-application.html) tutorial to create grails (version 2.3.1) application.

I am not using Maven and instead of MongoDb i'm using postgresql, but I believe these changes are not the things to be concerned for the issue I am facing.

After `$ grails integrate-with --intellij`, I ran the project on the intellij.
I am getting this error:

> ```
> Caught: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: grails for class: BuildConfig
> groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: grails for class: BuildConfig
>   at BuildConfig.run(BuildConfig.groovy:1)
> ```

I suspect that there may be some issue in **Framework Support**.
I googled for adding framework and according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757758/intellij-12-grails-2-1-configuration-grails-sdk-not-configured), Add Framework Support UI should show grails library, but for me it is not showing, please see the below screenshot.
[image: Framework support for Grails]

First question, is the error i am getting because of wrong framework (I suspect this because the error is saying no such property as grails), if so how to add grails framework support.

Secondly, If this is not the cause for the error then what else I am doing wrong ?

You can assume I am a newbie-newbie, I just started Grails for the first time in my life just half-an-hour back. So, you can point out any stupid mistakes I might have done.

Comment: Which version of Grails do you use ?

Comment: Grails version  2.3.1

Comment: Is this the community edition of IntelliJ?  You need the full "Ultimate" edition for Grails support

Comment: Yup!, but is there any way to work with community version ?

Comment: Not that I know of, you have to pay for the Ultimate Edition to work with Grails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grails is not supported in the Community Edition of IntelliJ.

You need to pay for the Ultimate Edition to use Grails

See the *"Frameworks and Technologies"* section here:

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html